# Front end form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find an answer to this.

I have a form that has to be submitted and the data to be processed entirely on the front end(in javascript). Is there a way that I can pass the form data to an action page and not to the same page. Right now I'm just emptying all data in the section and replacing it with the data that is being called; but I would like to do this similar to how a form would interact with php or python.

Thank you
-Art

Comment: Sounds like you need to submit the form using ajax, but both your issue and your intention are pretty unclear. What are you actually trying to do? What have you tried to achieve it?

Comment: At the moment I'm using an ajax call to grab data from a service when a user submits certain data. When the data is returned it clears the the div of all content and re renders the page from an inline template. Instead I would like to point the action to another page, say "results.html or .js" and either process all the data there and render an external template or loop through the data in an underscore template. Essentially I'm trying to grab form data that was submitted in a separate js file.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use HTML5 local or session storage to store all of the form values that a user enters and then on the new page use the stored values as you require.

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html